# is there any way to allow extensions in incognito mode by default?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, incognito-mode

I have made an extension for chrome and now I want it to work in incognito mode by default. I searched for a lot but did not get anything. I have read something about **selenium web driver**.

So is it possible to toggle incognito mode for chrome by using it?

If this is not possible without enabling by the end-user then how kids can be protected?

If an extension is specially made for protecting kids then simply they can disable in incognito mode.
So how it can be prevented?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: children who disable inclognito mode, can also delete the extension. :D

Comment: @fxnoob I have protected it somehow. So I only concern not to disable in incognito mode.

Comment: did you ever found out how i'm looking for this to ?

Answer (score 0):

As far it goes you cant disable ingonito mode on chrome unless you edit the chrome code..

However if the student is using chromebook you can disable it..
heres a link that will explain you

https://support.securly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023904553-How-to-disable-incognito-mode-in-Chromebooks-

P.S: ik i have bad spellings